# Why won't Vcl.Styles (RRUZ) install with Detours in Delphi 10.4.1 (latest)

Tags: delphi, detours

I've just installed a new VM for Delphi 10.4.1 Sydney.

1. My install path for Detours is C:\XE10\Detours
2. My Install path for Vcl.Styles is C:\XE10\Styles

Demos for the Detours work fine, but i noticed that the Detours unit is called "DDetours.pas" not "Detours.pas".

So when I attempt to compile and install the Vcl Styles Package, it states that a required package can not be found "Detours.pas".

I've spent two days tinkering with it, renaming units and such - and no luck.

Can you tell me what I need to do, in order to get Vcl Styles to compile and install ???

Thanks !

Comment: "Detours.pas* is not a package. What is the **exact** error message you're getting? Not a paraphrase, not an approximate, but the **exact** message.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install the "VisualStyles.dproj" project in order to use vcl-styles-utils.

You just need to add the units to the uses section as you can see in the demos.

However, if you prefer to use packages in your projects then you can use "VisualStyles.dproj" project but before installing it you will need to install Detours from this fork : https://github.com/salvadordf/DDetours